# Test obj.extend(Foo) with RSpec doubles

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

RSpec doubles can not be changed by extending its instances.

### Minimal example

Please note that the example described here is just a minimal example
to demonstrate the problem. The original classes are more complex and
the behavior that is specced (`obj.extend(Something)`) is needed and
can not be changed.

#### Spec

Let us have a look at the spec first.
In the following example you can see the spec how I'd like it to look like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Modifier do
  subject(:modifier) { described_class.new(active) }

  describe "#apply_to(obj)" do
    subject(:obj) { instance_double(Foo, foo: "foo") }

    before { modifier.apply_to(obj) }

    context "when active" do
      let(:active) { true }
      its(:foo) { is_expected.to eq("extended-foo") }  # NOTE: This one will fail
    end

    context "when not active" do
      let(:active) { false }
      its(:foo) { is_expected.to eq("foo") }
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this is not working :(

```
Failures:

  1) Modifier#apply_to(obj) when active foo should eq "extended-foo"
     Failure/Error: its(:foo) { is_expected.to eq("extended-foo") }

       expected: "extended-foo"
            got: "foo"
```

#### Foo

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :foo

  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end
end
```

#### Modifier

This class will modify given objects by extending its instance methods.

```
class Modifier
  def initialize(active)
    @active = active
  end

  # NOTE: This is the interesting method
  def apply_to(obj)
    return unless active?

    obj.extend(Extended)     # NOTE: And this is the interesting LOC
  end

  def active?
    @active
  end

  private

  attr_reader :active

  module Extended
    def foo
      "extended-#{super}"
    end
  end
end
```

### Even more minimal example

The whole problem can be broken down to the following code snippet:

```
module Bar
  def foo
    "bar"
  end
end

double = RSpec::Mocks::Double.new("Foo", foo: "foo")
obj = Object.new

double.extend(Bar)
obj.extend(Bar)

double.foo
# => "foo"

obj.foo
# => "bar"
```

### Conclusion

RSpec doubles can not be changed by extending its instances, which is expected behavior?

If so, how can you create readable specs for the example described here?

### Links

- Repo to reproduce: [Extend RSpec doubles (Example)](https://github.com/Deradon/extend-rspec-doubles-example)
- RSpec: [Using an instance double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double)
- GitHub: [RSpec Issue 1100](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1100)

Comment: Why not just `subject(:obj) { Foo.new('foo') }`?

Comment: Because this is a simplified example. In reality it is expensive to create this object. It would look more like: `Foo.new(lot, of, complex, arguments`) with a lot of dependencies. That's why I want to mock `Foo`.

Comment: Instead of mocking the real `Foo`, you could create an unnamed class via `Class.new { ... }`

Comment: @Stefan That is exactly the solution I am going with right now. Unfortunately than we will lose the ability to verify our doubles. (`instance_double` will verify that the interface you mock exists. So you can not stub non-existing methods. E.g.: `instance_double(Foo, bar: "bar")` will fail.)

Comment: But you are testing `Modifier`, not `Foo`. Why do have to verify `Foo`'s interface at that point?

Comment: @Stefan Because it is a good idea to verify that the classes your mock are implementing your stubbed methods. Otherwise you may end with stubbing methods that does not exist (anymore).

Answer (score 0):

If the spec *knows* that it expexts an extendend object, why not expect the `extend` call itself?

```
expect(obj).to receive(:extend).and_return { class.new.extend(...) }
```

Comment: I consider the `extend` implementation detail.
The same behavior can be achieved by: 

`def obj.foo; "extended-#{super}"; end`

By changing the implementation here, the specs would break :(